# Thread Pool System.OutOfMemory Exception while performing SQL job

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, sql-server-express, threadpool

I keep getting System.OutOfMemory exception in my WinForms App which is thrown while doing an SQL Update I guess. How can I fix that? Here is the case, I am using SQLEXPRESS, trying the code on a 32-bit machine so ThreadPool has default 1023 avaliable worker threads on startup.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{              
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Foo), myClass);
}

private void Foo(object state)
{
    //Some Stuff and SQL UPDATE
}
```

When the application starts, the ThreadPool starts with 8 threads and starts to increase allocated thread number to perform the job. A while later, it comes to 200 threads for example and can handle it no more, gives out System.OutOfMemory exception. When I check the stack trace, i can see that exception occurs in SQL operation of the method. What should I do? Do I need to increase Buffer Size of my database? I do not want to limit ThreadPools max size by the way or try Thread.Sleep() to have slower, less frequent requests to DB.

Comment: How much data do you request from the database?

Comment: do you really need so much thread? maybe you should use msmq and process with fairly low threads?

Comment: That is a lot of threads to start. But also I think the sheer size of your for loop is causing the out of memory exception. Break it into blocks, I don't think any memory gets released until the for loop completes.

Comment: I need many threads because the job has a time limit. Let Say i have to do that operation for 1.000.000 records in 1 hour.

Comment: A blunt solution: `ThreadPool.SetmaxThreads(16, 1000)`

Comment: @adt thanks for the suggestion, i will read it

Comment: "because the job has a time limit" - more reason to do it right. Spawning many threads isn't the way.

Comment: @Holterman, thank you Henk, can you please explain it a bit, how will it help me in theory.

Comment: You comment says you do 'Some Stuff' and a SQL UPDATE. What's the 'some stuff'? And does it necessarily have to be an UPDATE? If we know more about what you're trying to accomplish, we might have more suggestions.

Comment: @Holterman, if thats a 64 bit machine, how can I set the max thread number?

Comment: @Yagiz, using many threads does not necessarily make an operation go faster, because the threads have to share the same limited resources.  If you only have 4 ovens, using a million chefs doesn't mean you can cook a million meals in the time it would normally take to cook one.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for the tip. I just want to use maximum memory and space to operate at the same time to make the job faster. By some stuff I mean sending email to a user via SMTP. This app is for a telecommunication firm and its users.

Comment: Putting a SetmaxThreads in the beginning of your app limits the number of actual Threads. Use a low number for the first param. It might be a quick fix for your current code. But you probably need a better design.

Comment: @Yagiz: Be aware that some .NET objects also use ThreadPool threads under the covers.  It does sound like you need to think about your design, you have some real bottlenecks to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blindly creating lots of threads to make an operation go faster is not a good solution and almost never works (except by luck maybe). Keep in mind that each threads gets its own stack allocated which is 1MB by default I think. So in case you get 1000 threads going that will use 1GB of RAM just like that.

If you hit the DB then the work you can do in parallel will be very likely limited by disk I/O so throwing more threads at it might actually make it worse.

Also be aware that asynchroneous operations are executed on threadpool threads and if you tie them all up with your own work you may run into the problem to starve those operations (meaning they might be never or very late executed). The threadpool is designed to run only short lived tasks. If you need long running tasks then use a different threadpool (for example the [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx)) or create you own set of threads to handle the work.

Depending on what your SQL operations are you might hit the Large Object Heap fragmentation problem. Objects larger than 85.000 bytes are put on the LOH which is not being compacted and you can run into unexpected OOM ecceptions. So check if you are creating large arrays or lists of objects.

Otherwise: Use the [debugging tools for windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) to make a memory dump and look at what objects you have settings around eating all the memory and what holds the references to keep them alive. Alternatively you could use a .NET memory profiler but most of the really usefull ones are not free (however they usually come with a X days evaluation period).